# Is it possible to query PFSessions to see when users were 'last active?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an admin view that lists all of my parse users and I can't seem to figure out how to query Parse's new sessions class. I'm trying to show a label that says "last seen at: ____ " and fill in the blank with a date.  All my users are on running with up-to-date session tokens (I created the database after Parse did their switch over, so no migration necessary).

With the code below, I get an error:

"[Error]: no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.1)" 
nslog: last seen at: (null)

```
PFQuery *sessionQuery = [PFSession query];
[sessionQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:clientUserObject];
[sessionQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *session, NSError *error){

        NSDate *lastSeen = session.updatedAt;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastSeen];

        cell.lastSeenLabel.text = formattedDateString;
        NSLog(@"last seen at: %@", formattedDateString)
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not able to query "last seen" from the PFSession table. All entries of the table are automatically removed if the user logs out. So you're only able to find logged in users.

If you really want a "last seen" property, you should save it yourself in the PFUser table when you log out . Just add another column.

Hope this helps.